# Gmail Task API exist?

Tags: java, api, gmail, gdata-api

Inside Gmail, there is a small function called "Task". It can allow me to enter a to-do-list. I'm wondering if there is any official / unofficial Google API to access / update the list by Java language?

Comment: I think BrianH's answer counts as a definitive answer =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The official Google Task API has been released in May 2011 (Well, it's in Labs, but it is official)

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/

Here are the Java specific libraries:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Answer (score 10):

The official Google Tasks API doesn't exist as of now. There is a feature request open at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=987.

Answer (score 4):

If you sort the Google API issues by number of stars, this feature is overwhelmingly at the top of the list. There must be some political reason why they're not providing an API - this has been on the tracker for nearly 2 years now (added Jan 18, 2009).

```
Type         Priority Stars  Summary
Enhancement  Medium   4810   Request API for Tasks (in the Google Mail Interface)    
Enhancement  Low      158    structured fields wanted for postal addresses   
Enhancement  Medium   133    embed several private calendars in one iframe   
Defect       High     100    Lack of Individual Name Fields Causes Synchronization Problems with Mobile Devices      
Enhancement  ----     77     Upload arbitrary file types to standard accounts
```

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=985&sort=-stars%20priority&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Answer (score 2):

Its a perl module. Check it if it can help you.

**[nickspacek / Net-Google-Tasks](http://github.com/nickspacek/Net-Google-Tasks/)**

Answer (score 2):

Update - it seems as if it is on their task list for 2011, see this post from 13 January 2011:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/top-tasks-for-google-tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally, they released the API : http://code.google.com/intl/uk/apis/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's getting close.  http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=987